# MediaPlayer para após alguns segundos

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de rádio, para adquirir conhecimento, então peguei uma stream e peguei este código:

```
package tk.davidev.android.ews;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WebRadio extends AppCompatActivity {


private final static String stream = "http://170.75.144.170:10262/;";
Button play;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean started = false;
boolean prepared = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_radio);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWebRadio);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    play.setText("Carregando stream..");
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (started) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                started = false;
                play.setText("Play");
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                play.setText("Pausar");
            }

        }
    });

    new PlayTask().execute(stream);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   if(started)
        mediaPlayer.pause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!started)
        mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private class PlayTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        play.setEnabled(true);
        play.setText("Play");
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    }
}

}
```

Funciona! Porém apos uns 2/3 segundos ele para automaticamente, e se der Pause e Play ele não volta, só reiniciando a Activity.

Comment: tente [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241687/mediaplayer-stop-playing-after-about-5-seconds) solução no SO original! Espero que resulte!

Comment: Já tentei, porém, sem resultado.

Comment: Veja que ele instancia a classe ´Playtask´  e a executa no evento onCreate, então é natural que só funcione no momento da criação. Quanto a executar apenas alguns segundos eu imagino que é porque o stream que esse IP disponibiliza é apenas um demonstrativo pequeno mesmo.

Comment: A interrupção é sempre no mesmo ponto? Verifique como está o consumo de memória do app.

Comment: não, com outras apis funciona certinho.